# Create page forms with Share Point 2013

Tags: forms, sharepoint-2013

I want to create a simple web application with Sharepoint 2013. It is a home page that addresses several forms that each user can fill in all the forms and view the data you entered. Another superuser can view all completed forms by other users. Would he have to do with html + javascript + some database manager? Or could it be declaratively or unscheduled, with elements of SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InfoPath forms to allow user fill in data (all saved data stored in sharepoint list), and make custom view to present data stored in a list.

For creating custom view you can use Client Side Rendering (CSR), which just re-rending incoming data, or use Javascript Object Model (JSOM), which will connect to your sharepoint list and display it whatever you want.

If you don't know about these technologies you can read a lot:

Infopath: [InfoPath-Forms-Part](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/695909/InfoPath-Forms-Part)

CSR: [SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views), [Client-side-rendering-JS](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a)

JSOM: [How to: Retrieve List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the server on which I have to develop the application does not allow viewing InfoPath Forms. What alternative look better in this case? I read about some (new app model in SharePoint 2013 and Azure Hosted Apps;. Survey's Excel, Access Apps; FOSL (Forms on SharePoint Lists); Structured Data Forms ...) I am looking for a most simple and quick to implement solution. What do you recommend?

Comment: You can create your own wizard, using JavaScript or using existed solution, that need just to be adapted, for instance this one: http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples
If you want to separate the power-users and end-users data displaying you can use additional scripting, for example, create specific group and add power-users there, and then check is current user in correct group or not, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m
Of course you can create your own SharePoint-Hosted App.