# How to configure a column in my list on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-2013

I need to customize one or two columns in my list on SharePoint.

I need for the selected columns be restricted for editing by one group of users, while another group of users will have access to edit all columns in my list.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't.  Permissions are set on the list level, not any lower to things like fields or views.

The long answer is that there are lots of different tricks to make it look like you're granting view/field types of permissions, but as long as the data is in the same list, you need to grant access to those users or to a service account, etc...

See this: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3730d47f-6ba2-4ffd-ac05-567b042ff5c1/how-to-restrict-permissions-on-list-views?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

Answer (score 0):

Check whether current user belongs to a group by JSOM. [check this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122139/check-if-current-users-belongs-to-sp-group-using-javascript-client-side-object-m)

Then disable control by jQuery.

```
// Disable #x
$( "selector" ).prop( "disabled", true );

// Enable #x
$( "selector" ).prop( "disabled", false );
```

[jQuery selector](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)